# Findbugs is telling me that I have comparison of nonnegative value with -1 for no apparent reason

Tags: java, findbugs

I have this code which is showing up the following error in FindBugs:

[image]

```
Bug: Bad comparison of nonnegative value with -1 in hydra.extensions.drivers.eg2.internal.EG2GatewaySimulator$1.run()

This code compares a value that is guaranteed to be non-negative with a negative constant or zero. 

Rank: Scary (5), confidence: High
Pattern: INT_BAD_COMPARISON_WITH_NONNEGATIVE_VALUE 
Type: INT, Category: CORRECTNESS (Correctness)
```

For the code:

```
String receivedMessage = "";
char c;
boolean isValidChar;
do {
    c = (char) in.read();
    isValidChar = (c != '\r') && (c != -1);
    if (isValidChar) {
        receivedMessage += c;
    }
} while (isValidChar);
```

Comment: Sure. The OP was edited.

Comment: A `char` is an unsigned 16-bit integer. I can see that you're comparing `c`, which is a `char`, with `-1` in your code. That's why you get that warning.

Comment: really? chars are unsigned? never suspected it because read() returns -1 if the stream is closed. Now I get it why it return int not char... Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Value of char is 16 bit non-negative:

char: The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has a minimum value of '\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of '\uffff' (or 65,535 inclusive).

You are comparing it with -1.